# What type of worm is this?

Tags: species-identification

Found this on the carpet in our office(North Carolina), no idea how it got there.
It is at between 8 and 12 inches long.
[image]

Comment: It looks desiccated and I think that's why it has this weird shape. Was it moving when you clicked this pic?

Comment: It was not moving.